# Distributing MySQL storage to drives by function

Tags: mysql, filesystems

I'm wondering if MySQL has any capability to specify that data belonging to a certain account (representing e.g., a particular app, or a particular corporate program) be stored at at some particular place in the filesystem (such as a particular drive or RAID), instead of bundling it inside the same physical file structure that is shared by every other account, table, and data element managed by MySQL for everybody on that server.

I'm aware that I can jigger MySQL to store its entire data bundle at a place other than the default place, but I was hoping there might be a way to do this by function, for "some data but not all data."

Comment: Why you would do that depends on what your requirement it. Alternate solutions may also be unacceptable because the same requirement. So, what is your requirement? aka what are you trying to achieve at a high level. Please don't just say the question again. This question is too broad, focus it considerably or it will get closed without an answer. Welcome to SO.

Comment: The existing applications deal in small amounts of data for which the space available on the boot drive and traditional backup considerations are sufficient. The new application is going to have quite a bit larger dataset and needs to be stored on a multiply-redundant RAID array of large drives. It would be convenient to leave the existing data where it is and just tell MySQL to put the new stuff on the new drives.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, there are options to specify the location for each table or tablespace. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-table-external.html

In earlier versions of MySQL, these options didn't work consistently. You could specify the directory for individual table partitions, if your table was partitioned, but not for a non-partitioned table. Go figure. :-)

That said, I've never encountered a situation where it was worth the time to specify the physical location of tables. Basically, if your performance depends on the difference between one RAID filesystem vs. carefully choosing among different drives, you're already losing.

Instead, I've always done this approach:

1. Use one `datadir` on a fast RAID filesystem. Use the default configuration of all tables and logs under this datadir.
2. Allocate as much RAM as I can afford to the InnoDB buffer pool (up to the size of the database of course - no need to use more RAM than that). RAM is orders of magnitude faster than any disk, even an SSD. So you'd prefer to be reading data out of RAM.

If that's not enough performance, there are other things you can do to optimize, like creating indexes, or modifying the application code to do more caching to reduce database reads, or using a message queue to postpone database writes.

If that's still not enough performance, then scale out to multiple database servers. In other words, sharding.

Comment: The original impetus wasn't performance-related (it's a multiplexed RAID, not a striped RAID). It was more a question of free space and integrity against loss due to failure. Plus, it just seemed like the cleanest architecture for data management and organization.

Comment: I'd rather create more space by combining multiple drives into a RAID-0 array.

Comment: Not an option for the boot drive, sorry. I already have two large RAID-0 arrays as externals, I don't intend to buy another just to keep SQL happy. This is large archival information, not information for constant and speedy retrieval.

Comment: Okay one other tip: You can use symbolic links for certain schemas. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/symbolic-links.html I'd do it at the schema level, not per-table, because symlinks for tables are undone when you ALTER TABLE.

Comment: There seems to be promise here, but it is far from straightforward. I avoided trying this originally because of the many sources I encountered that claimed that MySQL does not work or play well with such symlinks. 

Indeed, page
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html says:

   Creating a database directory by manually creating a directory under
the data directory (for example, with mkdir) is unsupported in MySQL
8.0.

which not only seems to conflict with the instructions on the page you provided, but in trying out those instructions, they fail for me.

Comment: I created a database in place, then stopped the server, moved the database dir to the external pack, created a symlink, then restarted the server. The database and its tables all show as existing, but any attempt to access actual data fails with "Error retrieving table information: An error occurred while retrieving the information for table 'Garbage'. Please try again. MySQL said: Tablespace is missing for table `remotedatabase`.`garbage`.

Comment: I'd be checking that the copied files have the right file ownership (`mysql`) and file permissions. Use `chown` and `chmod` to fix them. You haven't said if you're using Linux, but selinux/apparmor can also hinder MySQL if you put files in a nonstandard location. Either reconfigure the mysql policy or else turn off those security enforcers.

Comment: I'm using MacOS. Everything has been chowned to _mysql:_mysql, down to and including the symlink itself. In the example where I created the database first and then moved it elsewhere, all the ownership and access parameters were transferred intact and then verified, so I don't think I have an access issue. In the example where I set up the symlink first and then expected MySQL to create the database through it, it would have set up whatever access it wanted, but just punted entirely instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need also since 8.0.21 you need also to consider adding the new direcTory to the configuration

> CREATE TABLESPACE tablespace_name ADD DATAFILE ‘/my/table/space/dir’;

> However, that directory must be known to InnoDB. Known directories are defined by the following settings: datadir,  innodb_data_home_dir,  innodb_undo_directory  &  innodb_directories.

Also Luuk pointed out you need `innodb_file_per_table=1` for it to remove the error message

```
Error Code: 3121. The DATAFILE location must be in a known directory.
```

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-consistency-for-datafile-locations-in-mysql-8-0-21/)

Also in [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-table-external.html)

Comment: or docs: [15.6.1.2 Creating Tables Externally](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-table-external.html). It says you need: `innodb_file_per_table=1` and `innodb-directories` should have an acceptable value